# Rails f.select does not style with bootstrap class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a select field, for selecting a date(year)

```
  <%= f.select :finishdate, (Time.zone.now.year - 30)..(Time.zone.now.year) + 5, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

But i does not style itself even though I used bootstrap style. Its not styling the select with bootstrap, but instead using no style.

Comment: Can you show the html that's being generated? I believe the `select` method takes options and then html options.
`select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <%= f.select :finishdate, (Time.zone.now.year - 30)..(Time.zone.now.year) + 5, {}, class: "form-control" %>
```

[See here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) for method `select`

You need to pass your html options *(e.g. class: " ")* without `{}` as per the select method syntax style.

Comment: @GurmukhSingh okay, i have updated my answer, hope it helps!!